# Adding a new column in a Dataframe based on two conditions from two different columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame containing two rows: `car` is a model of car and `num` is the number of cars of that model that I have observed in a car park.

Using `dplyr::mutate()`, I want add another column, `pop_car` (popular cars), which repeats the car brand name if it has `num > 1` and shows `"Other"` if `num = 1`.

```
car <- c("Audi", "Toyota", "Nissan", "Ford", "Hyundai", "Mercedes")
num <- c(5,3,1,4,4,1)
 
df <- data.frame(car, num)

df

#         car num  
# 1      Audi   5    
# 2    Toyota   3    
# 3    Nissan   1    
# 4      Ford   4    
# 5   Hyundai   4    
# 6  Mercedes   1
```

I'm trying to write code to get the dataframe to look like this:

```
 car     num  pop_car
Audi      5    Audi
Toyota    3    Toyota
Nissan    1    Other  
Ford      4    Ford
Hyundai   4    Hyundai
Mercedes  1    Other
```

so far I've tried

```
df |>
mutate(pop_car = df$car if num >1) |>
  if_else(pop_car = other if num == 1 )
```

Also  when answering please pretend that this is a much longer data frame, which means avoid writing down the car brands in the function

Comment: `...mutate(pop_car = ifelse(num == 1, 'Other', car))`

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide the example dataset that you wish for us to use. Also use the dplyr variant of `ifelse`, namely `if_else`. And also, the `if_else` has to be within the mutate, not outside of it. See @Sotos' comment for the correct usage.

Comment: doesn't work. Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Did you try it like this? `df %>% mutate(pop_car = ifelse(num == 1, 'Other', car))`

Comment: Ok I got it finally thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
require(dplyr)
mutate(df, pop_car = ifelse(num > 1, pop_car, "Other"))
```